# How to show many to many values in view table without duplicate

Tags: laravel

Hello i am doing a panel where a client can select one or multiple products and make an order. I have made the table connection for many to many.
This is the migration code for ordering table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('order_number')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('client')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('products')->nullable();
        $table->string('amount')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('client')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('products')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
     });
    }
```

This is the `store` method that i have made in the `OrderController` :

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'order_number' => 'required',
            'client' => 'required',
            'products' => 'required',
            'amount' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($request->products); $i++)
        {
            $values[] = [
                'order_number' => $request->order_number,
                'client' => $request->client,
                'products' => $request->products[$i],
                'amount' => $request->amount[$i],
                'description' => $request->description,
            ];
            $amount = Product::findorFail($request->products[$i]);
            $total_value = $request->amount[$i] + $amount->amount;
            $amount->update(['amount'=>$total_value]);
        }
        
        Order::upsert($values,'order_number');
        return redirect('/')->with('msg', 'Order Saved successfully!');
    }
```

If i make `dd` i will have an array.
This is an image how the table order looks like after one user has made one order with many products selected:

[image]

Now i want to have a table where i can show the results from the database and it looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to make it show only one row without duplicating 3 times?

This is the code of this view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="wrapper-index">
        <h1>Total Products</h1>

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Order Number</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($orders as $order)
                <tr>
                    <td> {{$order->order_number}} </td>
                    <td> {{$order->client}} </td>
                    <td> {{$order->description}} </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{route('orders.show',$order->id)}}">
                            <button>Edit</button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{route('orders.destroy',$order->id)}}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')
                            <button>Delete</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        <p class="msg">{{session('msg')}}</p>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to display? all orders? All products in one order?

Comment: Your database structure doesn't seem to be valid. Feels like you should have many to many relation between Order and Product. In that case you will have unique order numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is the solution,

- It's simple..
- You have many-to-many relationship between products and the orders tables.
- You can get unique data by using ***groupBy()*** method.
- group the products with order_id(order_number).
- Get the order details by database like this way and return the data to your blade file,

> ```
> public function index()
> {
>     $orders = Order::with('client','products')->groupBy('order_number')->get();
>     return view('orders.index', compact('orders'));
> }
> ```

*Hope you will fix this issue...*